# How to get the data-attributes of radio buttons to change a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a form that updates a base price after the customer selects options in radio buttons. The `value=""` of each one is taken so I am using data-attributes, but the price is not updating after selecting a radio button.

I have tried several ways with the functions but I just can't find what I am doing wrong. I cannot use the `innerHTML` inside the function, it has to be outside cause later I need to take the result of the selection and sum it to other numbers (but this is another story).

```js
var hammer = 0;

function productCost() {
  document.getElementById("_form_29_").onchange = function() {
    hammer = document.querySelector('input[name = field]:checked').getAttribute('data-cost');
  };
}
productCost();
document.getElementById("options_cost").innerHTML = productCost();
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="https://tmgmfg.activehosted.com/proc.php" id="_form_29_" class="build-form" validate>
  <label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Manual SPT Hammer" data-cost="0"/>Manual SPT Hammer</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Automatic SPT Hammer" data-cost="2000">Automatic SPT Hammer</label>
</form>
<div id="options_cost"></div>
```

Comment: You retrieve the attribute-value, but you never do anything with it (in the code you've provided).

Comment: I thought I was updating hammers value from 0 to whatever the user selects. And then using productCost(), putting it in the HTML @DavidThomas What am I missing? Could you point it out please?

Comment: You assign the `data-cost` attribute to the `hammer` variable, but nowhere do you add that variable to the document.

Comment: Well even if I put hammer in the .innerHTML, instead of productCost(), it does not updated. So I tried that but didn't work.

Comment: If you need the data-cost value, you may consider to use a dataset list and collect the values from an event handler

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need in the `change` event handler:

```
document.getElementById("options_cost").innerHTML = document.querySelector("input[name=field]:checked").getAttribute("data-cost");
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("_form_29_").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("options_cost").innerHTML = document.querySelector("input[name=field]:checked").getAttribute("data-cost");
  };
};
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="https://tmgmfg.activehosted.com/proc.php" id="_form_29_" class="build-form" validate>
<label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Manual SPT Hammer" data-cost="0"/>Manual SPT Hammer</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Automatic SPT Hammer" data-cost="2000">Automatic SPT Hammer</label>
</form>
<div id="options_cost"></div>
```

Comment: Hello @PeterKA thank you for your response. Unfortunately is is necessary that the result is out of the function, so that I can continue with the rest of the code. Later I will need to sum several of these radio button groups and I cannot do it if the results are in the functions. Or I am wrong? Please correct me if I am.

Comment: Feel free to rearrange to serve your needs. At least you have a working snippet upon which to build.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that works:

```js
function productCost () {
  // retrieving the relevant checked <input> element:
  let hammer = document.querySelector('input[name=field]:checked')
    // using the HTMLElement.dataset API to retrieve
    // the 'data-cost' attribute-value:
    .dataset.cost;
  // finding the element with id="options_cost", assigning the
  // 'hammer' variable as its textContent:
  document.getElementById('options_cost').textContent = hammer;
}

// retrieving all <input> elements with name="field":
document.querySelectorAll('input[name=field').forEach(
  // using NodeList.forEach() to iterate over the
  // NodeList returned from document.querySelectorAll(),
  // using an Arrow function expression (as we don't need
  // to access 'this'):
  (inputElement) => {
    // inputElement is the current Node of the NodeList
    // we're iterating over; and here we use the
    // EventTarget.addEventListener() method to bind
    // the productCost() function - note the deliberate
    // lack of parentheses - as the event-handler for
    // the 'change' event:
    inputElement.addEventListener('change', productCost);
  });
```

```css
#options_cost:empty::before {
  content: 'Please select an item above.';
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="https://tmgmfg.activehosted.com/proc.php" id="_form_29_" class="build-form" validate>
  <label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Manual SPT Hammer" data-cost="0"/>Manual SPT Hammer</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Automatic SPT Hammer" data-cost="2000">Automatic SPT Hammer</label>
</form>
<div id="options_cost"></div>
```

References:

- [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLElement.dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- [`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Comment: Wow @David Thomas, good answer. Unfortunately is is necessary that the result is out of the function, so that I can continue with the rest of the code. Later I will need to sum several of these radio button groups and I cannot do it if the results are in the functions. Or I am wrong? Please correct me if I am.

Comment: Can you show enough of your code that I can see what you're doing? The easiest way would be to iterate through the `<form>` looking for relevant `<input>` or `<select>` elements in one function, and update the value in one place rather than multiple different functions.

Comment: Would I get banned for putting the link to the page? I hope not. https://tmgmfg.com/build.php

So far I am only working in the first group of radio buttons.

Comment: You may not get banned, but your [mcve] code needs to be in your question, otherwise - once your problem is solved - your site will no longer host the code that's problematic. Also, don't use url-shorteners. Please see the guidance on Meta Stackoverflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/82548

Comment: Hello David! I have made some changes but it is still not working. I passed the selected value of the data attribute to a `<p>` so it is accesible globally. The problem is that for some reason I cannot get it back.

`window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("_form_29_").onchange = function() {
            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = document.querySelector('input[name = field]:checked').getAttribute('data-cost');
        };
        }
        
        var hammer = document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML;`

Comment: Here it is a fiddle with what I have, for some reason I can't get the content of`<p id="cost"></p>`.
https://jsfiddle.net/n4cykb6x/